# Ubuntu 13.10 some System Settings reset after reboot (Touch-Pad disable)

Tags: 13.10, touchpad, system-settings

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on an ASUS M70SA notebook (and recognised as such during install).
Every time I boot, I have to go into System Settings to turn off my Touch-Pad.  Once I make the change, it works for the remainder of the session.  What I don't understand is why my choice is forgotten between boots.

How can this be fixed?

Cheers,
Nap

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and it's even reset after suspend/hybernate also. It's been reported, I bet it will be fixed in 14.04.

Also, I found that when I'm going to settings I have to click twice on the deactivate button, like it was deactivated and I had to activate/deactivate to make sure it's off.

I've been using a touchpad indicator that I could fast switch on/off and it was keeping the setting found here: [Atareao-team](https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/atareao).

Comment: I also have to slide the slider twice to make it stick.

Comment: I found elsewhere the following command:
`sudo rmmod psmouse` which disables the touch-pad and (from my experience) fixes a mouse click problem I've been having.

Comment: this "hack" sounds nice. `rmmod` removes the PS2 Mouse module (driver) and disables the touchpad (that in most laptops is PS2 connected). you can make it permanent by putting a new line with `blacklist psmouse` in the blacklist modules file, fast way:

`sudo echo "blacklist psmouse" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-psmouse.conf`